# moving identity tables to your own

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

i've got this error ***The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context*** i kind of feel where is my error but i don't find a way to correct it 
i guess the problem is about using your own tables but keep the identity implementation so i've got to map my tables to the one in entity ,i am  learning so don't feel uncomfortable to even explain basics if you feel i need it

**IdentityModel..ApplicationUser**

```
namespace Mvc.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }



    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
        }


        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
            // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());

        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountController**

```
namespace Mvc.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        vendrEntities dc = new vendrEntities();
        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
         //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:

                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });
                }
                FillShoppingCart(model.Email, model.Password);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        }
    }
}
```

**startup.auth**

```
  using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Mvc.Models;
using Owin;
using System;

namespace Mvc
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    //OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    //    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    //    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");
        }

    }
}
```

**webConfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ARPA;Initial Catalog=MyShop;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  <add name="vendrEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ARPA;initial catalog=MyShop;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what is your problem?? You haven't clearly mentioned even once

Comment: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Comment: In which line you are getting the error?

Comment: the error is in accountcontroller login and register